# MongoDB copyDatabase command succsefasully copies database, but gives me a different size on the ner server

Tags: mongodb

So I have to move this one database to another server and I'm using the MongoDB [copyDatabase](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/) command.

It looks like it successfully copies it over, but there is a 3x difference in size between the two servers. It has the same amount of objects and collections though...

db.stats() for the first server:

```
> use myProjDb;
switched to db myProjDb
> db.stats
function (scale){
    return this.runCommand( { dbstats : 1 , scale : scale } );
}
> db.stats();
{
    "db" : "myProjDb",
    "collections" : 9,
    "objects" : 892,
    "avgObjSize" : 303.76681614349775,
    "dataSize" : 270960,
    "storageSize" : 1609728,
    "numExtents" : 18,
    "indexes" : 10,
    "indexSize" : 106288,
    "fileSize" : 201326592,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "dataFileVersion" : {
        "major" : 4,
        "minor" : 5
    },
    "extentFreeList" : {
        "num" : 0,
        "totalSize" : 0
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
> ^C
bye
```

db.stats() for the new one after I copy it over. CoreReports is the new name.:

```
> use CoreReports
switched to db CoreReports
> db.stats();
{
    "db" : "CoreReports",
    "collections" : 9,
    "objects" : 892,
    "avgObjSize" : 397.13004484304935,
    "dataSize" : 354240,
    "storageSize" : 663552,
    "numExtents" : 17,
    "indexes" : 10,
    "indexSize" : 106288,
    "fileSize" : 67108864,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "dataFileVersion" : {
        "major" : 4,
        "minor" : 5
    },
    "extentFreeList" : {
        "num" : 0,
        "totalSize" : 0
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
> ^C
bye
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not exactly clear which part you are concerned about, but I think there are two possibilities - storage size and average object and data size.

If you mean the object and data size differences, what version are the two instances running? Version 2.6 switched to use [usePowerOf2Sizes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/#storage) as the default allocation method (instead of the previous exact fit allocation method), and the only difference is in the objects (the indexes are the same size) which suggests that as a possible cause.  If they are both on 2.6 it's worth checking to see if the settings on the original database might have been altered (see the same link above for how that is done).

In terms of the differences in storage size, the original database most likely just has fragmentation (from deletes, updates, moves etc.).  If you ran a [repair](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/) to rewrite it from scratch (which is what you are doing when you copy it over) you would see identical (or close to it) results.

Comment: The parts I was concerned about were fileSize and dataSize. I'll have to investigate it more later, I'm not sure which version they're using. Thanks!